# postgresql numeric to timestamp conversion timezone issue

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to convert a numeric to timestamp in postgresql. However, it always converts it in EST timezone. Before running the query, I try the following.

```
set time zone 'UTC+10';

select to_timestamp(r.date/1000) as current_email_timestamp
FROM email;
```

However, It the timestamp always seem to be in US timezone. The emails are mostly sent during working hours but when I change the numeric back to timestamp with above query, it shows all the emails at night time

Could it be that the timestamp in numeric was stored in US timezone, or could it be that when converting back from numeric to timestamp, it is not coverting the timezone correctly.

Can someone please tell me how to fix this

Regards
Arif

Comment: Can you show us what the input numerics look like?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `at time zone` modifier:

```
select to_timestamp(1411738200), 
       to_timestamp(1411738200) at time zone 'America/Chicago', 
       to_timestamp(1411738200) at time zone 'UTC+10'
```

Your postgres installation probably defaults to EST.